# Why font seems smaller on mobile or tablet than the corresponding browser size?

Tags: css, responsive, font-size

When resizing the browser to the width of different mobile and tablet screens, the font seems fine readable and big enough, but when i check the website on my tablet the font seems smaller and not enough readable.

I thought that the browser is a real indicator of what the website should look like in smaller screen devices, but this seems not the case, as font looks small in my tablet screen.

So why font is not shown on the smaller devices as the same as the browser when resized to the same size??

Comment: Have you included a viewport meta tag in your HTML?

Comment: thank you this seems to be the solution, i included the meta tag already but there was some typo that made it not work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The viewport meta tag tells the browser that your site is responsive ready and allows the browser to scale your site to device pixels rather than actual pixels. This should emulate a narrower viewport with the content appearing larger on screen at a more natural size. This tag should be placed in the `head` section of your HTML file.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```